# Does the iTunes Connect app setup screen provide any indication of proper upload?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

I'm working on submitting an iOS app to the App Store, and I just completed the final build step that involves archiving from Xcode & distributing via the Organizer.  This step was completed using the same login details used on the iTunes Connect site.

Everything appeared to work successfully with the build/distribution process, and I was provided with a screen that said my app has been submitted for review.  However, I'm not seeing any change to the iTunes Connect screen (see screenshot below).

Does this mean that I submitted wrong?  If so, how can I associate my build with the application record in iTunes Connect?

[image: iTunes Connect 'Build' section]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to the `Prerelease` section.  There you will see your uploaded builds.  It will take around 10 minutes to process then you will see a `+` beside `Build`, where you can choose the build that you want to submit for review.

Comment: Ahh, now I see there's a record in there with a "Processing" status.  Thanks so much!